# You save a library as a file as you **do** a model - or **do with**?

Tags: phrase-usage

In context, the sentence *You save a library as a file as you do a model* is meant to mean that you can save a library as a file just like you can save a model as a file, assuming the reader knows how to do the latter.

I was wondering if the sentence lacks a *with*, and should indeed be corrected to *You save a library as a file as you do **with** a model*.

Comment: Yes, you have to do something to clarify you mean (A) model->file, not (B) library->model. (B): You save a library as a file the way you save it as a model.

Comment: You can save a library as a file, as you would do with a model -- would get my vote.  I'd look for maximum clarity instead of succinctness.

Comment: The statement was absolutely fine without any "with."

More usefully, what made you doubt that?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that either "*with*" or "*for*" is necessary. Without a preposition, the erroneous interpretation of a model being created or worked upon at the same time is otherwise obtrusive.

*For*

- ([ref.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Employee_Handbook/DgTvfb3jBBoC?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22as+you+do+for%22&dq=%22as+you+do+for%22&printsec=frontcover)) ... as you do for annual leave. You'll have to fill out Form 71 "Application for Leave" and give the name and address of the doctor with whom you have the appointment.
- ([ref.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Agressologie/Xl1QAAAAYAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22as+you+do+for%22&dq=%22as+you+do+for%22&printsec=frontcover)) No , you do not get the same sioichimetry from fluorescence quenching as you do for polarization

*With*

- ([ref.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Tax_reform/qURkAAAAIAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22as+you+do+with%22&dq=%22as+you+do+with%22&printsec=frontcover)) and you should tax the profit or the net income, or what have you, as a result of it, just as you do with taxable corporations.
- ([ref.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22as%20you%20do%20with%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)) The important point is to get in the same habit of entering your expenses as they occur, or at the end of the day as you do with your business cards.

Answer (score 0):

When a sentence element is repeated, it is often possible to omit the second instance when it is obvious. In order for this sentence to have the unintended meaning, the subordinate clause would have to be interpreted as omitting both the direct object and the preposition:

> You save a library as a file as you do [[a library]] [[as]] a model.

However, this is unusual for two reasons: 1) The direct object is omitted but not the entire prepositional phrase. 2) The preposition is omitted but not its object. I therefore think that it is unlikely that anyone would interpret the sentence this way (as long as that person was being careful).

That being said, I still think that too much is being omitted. I would probably include all of the elements in the subordinate clause:

> You save a library as a file just as you save a model as a file.

(The second "as" has a different meaning from the first one, so I included "just" to make the distinction a bit clearer.)